# Targeting Pure elements in next.js with CSS modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm porting an app from React to Next and I keep getting an error with my css: "ul" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id).

I'm using css modules and am not sure what the workaround is to keep everything in the css module.

**for example:**

index.js

```
<div className={styles.container}>
  <ul>
    <li>Person One</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

index.module.css

```
.container{
  background-color: pink;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none; //this throws an error
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try giving a className or id to ul tag and then write your styles accordingly.

**for example:**

index.js

```
<div className={styles.container}>
 <ul className={styles.container__list}>
  <li>Person One</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

index.module.css

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
}
.container__list{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

If you don't want to use classes as mentioned @Zeeshan's answer, you cannot use the module-based CSS. You will need to use a global stylesheet to target pure elements as selectors. They cannot be component-scoped.

Further, you can only import a global stylesheet in one place (`_app.tsx/_app.jsx/_app.js`), or you'll receive an error ([explained here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/errors/css-global.md)).

You may break your styles out across many stylesheets, but they all have to be global, so there's probably little benefit from doing so.

To **quote directly** from [this Next.js GitHub discussion forum](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12510#discussioncomment-81624):

> You are receiving this error because you are using html tags directly
> instead of classnames or ids in a file extension that is probably
> **[filename].module.(css | scss | sass)**
>
> File extensions with ***.module.(css | scss | sass)** are css modules
> and they can only target elements using classnames or ids and not
> using tag names. Although this is possible in other frameworks like
> create-react-app, it is not possible in next-js.
>
> My suggestion is using these html selector css in a separate file that
> doesn't contain the '.module' in it. Example: **[filename].(css | scss
> | sass)** --> **styles.scss**
>
> And instead of importing like this
>
> `import styles from './styles.module.scss';`
>
> import like this
>
> `import './styles.scss';`

Comment: It gives a warning that such imports import './styles.scss'; has to be there in _app.tsx, not any other component.

Comment: @AniruddhaShevle you're right. It needs to be in that one component. I will update my answer.

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: Why in angular and svelte it is possible to have component-scoped pure selectors, but in nextjs not?

Comment: @oleggabureac Angular appears to take pure selectors and transforms them into more targeted selectors... If you put a style on an `h1` in an component's css file, then the selector that ends up scoped to the component with its unique identifier like `h1[ng_content-fmj-c345]`, for example.

Comment: I understand, but why next can't do that? It is so hard to imlement it? It seems like an incomplete feature.

Answer (score 8):

This is actually extremely simple.

You can add a container class to the top element (just like you did), and then use combinators ( ,`+`,`>`, etc.) to target pure elements as you wish.

**For example:**

index.js:

```
<div className={styles.container}>
    <ul>
        <li>Person One</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

index.module.css:

```
.container {
  background-color: pink;
}
.container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: This fails if the pure elements have pseudo states like `.container ul:hover` reports issues.