# Syntax error: Selector "input[type='checkbox'], in css modules react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a checkbox bigger in the `modules.css` react based project but it is not working.

Here is my HTML code snippet :

```html
     <div className={styles.row}>
        <label className={styles.label}>Netflix</label>
        <input className={styles.checkbox} id="name" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
```

and here is my **css code snippet**

```css
.checkbox {
    height: 2.4em;
    width: 2.4em;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: .8rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@supports (-webkit-appearance: none) or (-moz-appearance: none) {
    input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio'] {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
    }
}
```

and I am getting **error** like this below :

> ./styles/Home.module.css:82:2
>
> Syntax error: Selector "input[type='checkbox'],   input[type='radio']"
> is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or
> id)
>
> 80 |    81 | @supports(-webkit-appearance: none) or
> (-moz-appearance: none) {
> 82 |   input[type='checkbox'],
> |  ^   83 |   input[type='radio'] {   84 |     -webkit-appearance: none;

Comment: like the error message says, in CSS Modules, a selector must contain at least one local class or id. `input[type='checkbox']` contains no class, no id. `.row input[type='checkbox']` contains a class.

Comment: `input.checkbox[type='checkbox']` you already have class `.checkbox`.

Comment: i did this for that checkbox but changes are not working                                                           ``` .row input[type='checkbox']:checked::after {
  content: "✔";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 90%;
  left: 0.0625em;
  top: -0.25em;
}                                                                                                                                                                             ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985543/selector-global-class-is-not-pure-pure-selectors-must-contain-at-least-one

Comment: not working still no effect on UI

Answer (score -1):

Hi Try the below solution, it's working fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .checkbox {
            height: 2.4em;
            width: 2.4em;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: .8rem;
            border-radius: 10%;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #41B883;

        }

        @supports (-webkit-appearance: none) or (-moz-appearance: none) {
            input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio'] {
                -webkit-appearance: none;
                -moz-appearance: none;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this question is for react CSS modules :(