# Syntax error: Selector "html" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

Tags: javascript, css, next.js

In Next.js project I add in _app.js

```
import '../src/styles/style.module.scss';
import '../src/styles/main.module.scss';
```

main.module.scss content:

```
// ./src/styles/main.module.scss
  @tailwind base;
  @import "~tailwindcss/base";
  @import "~tailwindcss/components";
  @import "~tailwindcss/utilities";

  // NProgress style.
  @import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
```

But everytime I get:

```
./src/styles/main.module.scss:1:1
Syntax error: Selector "html" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

> 1 | @tailwind base;
```

Comment: I don't use tailwind, but wound't `@import "~tailwindcss/base";` want to come before -> `@tailwind base;` ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selector ":global .class" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65985543/selector-global-class-is-not-pure-pure-selectors-must-contain-at-least-one)

Answer (score 0):

make sure you dont use impure selectors as (body,html,h1,p,etc...).

you can read this about non-pure selectors https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/16050

Comment: I try use this app and this is original files https://github.com/imranhsayed/woo-next/tree/master/src/styles